# Parameterised dynamic where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(MAX)<br />
DECLARE @Count NVARCHAR(MAX)<br />
SET @Query =' AND IsActive=1'
SET @Count=(SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM tbl_Id WHERE Id='9' + @Query)<br />
SELECT @Count
```

The problem is `@Count` always returns zero but if I remove `@Query` from query then it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see.  You have a `WHERE` clause that specifies:

```
WHERE id = '9 AND IsActive = 1'
```

That seems like a really strange value for a column called `id`, so I'm not surprised the query doesn't find any.

You seem to want dynamic SQL:

```
SET @Query = '
SELECT @Count = COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_id
WHERE id = ''9''
';

SET @Count = @Query + ' AND IsActive = 1';

EXEC sp_executesql @query,
                   N'@Count int output',
                   @Count=@Count;
```